# How do I add a contact from within Gmail's contact interface to Google Plus circles?

Tags: google, google-plus, google-contacts

I find it rather tedious to add a contact from within Google+ interface to a circle.  I would rather add the contact from within the contacts section in Gmail.  Is this possible?

Better yet, can it automatically add/create contacts to circles in Google+ from my groups that I've already associated my contacts to?

Answer (score 3):

It is not currently possible.  When adding a contact to a circle in Google+, that contact does show up in [Gmail contacts](https://mail.google.com/mail/#contacts) and in [Google Contacts](http://contacts.google.com).  What gets added to the contacts database is a new contact with a a url entry titled "profile" and with a Google profile url, e.g. mine is https://www.google.com/profiles/106258285517412659099.  Part of being a contact in Google+ is being in a circle.  From Google or Gmail contacts, there is no way to designate a circle.  There is also no way from the API to do this currently as well.

Comment: That's so terrible!  If google's purpose is to move us further into the cloud, and bring better connectivity, then why not bring a more seamless interface between those apps?  Thanks for research thus far.  Hopefully this will change soon.

Comment: @KronoS in all fairness, the system is **very** new, but yes, hopefully it will be implemented.

Comment: @Trufa although it's new, the whole purpose has been said as a contact management... I would assume that would include actual contact management :P  But yes let's hope it works out in the end.

Comment: You understand it's still in field trial, right?